# Specifying caret position in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

When typing `foo` I want AutoHotKey insert `foo % bar` and place caret at `%`, so I can type something there. Is it possible? What about following:

```
 <a src="%placeholder1%"> %placeholder2% </a> %placeholder3%
```

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is [caret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation).

Answer (score 2):

You can specify to move left after replacing a hotstring with the {left n} command.  Like so:

```
::foo::foo bar{left 4}
```